# Call js function

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

```
<div id="picker-updatedDate{%= ID %}" class="bordForTdPickerTables cellPadding cellNotEditable lastUpdateDIV">{%= ConvertDateFromMSajax2JSFullDateStr(EnteredWhen) %}</div>
```

But the function `ConvertDateFromMSajax2JSFullDateStr` doesn't get called.

How can I call the function?

Comment: I don't understand. Where are you calling a JS function?

Comment: `<div id="picker-updatedDate{%= ID %}" onload="ConvertDateFromMSajax2JSFullDateStr('{%= EnteredWhen %}')" class="bordForTdPickerTables cellPadding cellNotEditable lastUpdateDIV"></div>` That?

Comment: @Lorenzo This looks like classic asp, which is never fun.

Comment: what should be done so that it knows how to call this function?

Comment: @Mikhail if this is classic asp, retag your question with asp-classic.

Comment: @Mikhail: Why are you using `{%=` and `%}` instead of `<%=` and `%>`? Also, can you post the code for the `ConvertDateFromMSajax2JSFullDateStr` function and value for the `EnteredWhen` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ConvertDateFromMSajax2JSFullDateStr` is client side JavaScript function and you want to pouplate the `div` with its output, passing server side argument, first have this code in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
   var oDiv = document.getElementById("picker-updatedDate<%=ID%>");
   oDiv.innerHTML = ConvertDateFromMSajax2JSFullDateStr("<%=EnteredWhen%>");
}
</script>
```

Then correct syntax for the div itself is:

```
<div id="picker-updatedDate<%=ID%>" class="bordForTdPickerTables cellPadding cellNotEditable lastUpdateDIV"></div>
```

Make sure to have the code assigning values to `ID` and `EnteredWhen` variables before the above.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear and your code is syntactically incorrect.  As others have pointed out, there is no javascript function provided in your example.

ASP delimiters are "<%  %>" not "{%  %}"

To "call" a function in ASP you can use :

<% call MyFunctionName() %>

However, by using the explicit call statement, no value is returned from the function.

if the function is to return a value then omit the call statement:

<%= MyFunctionName() %>